# Flutter it possible to pass a MultiProvider inside a MaterialApp?

Tags: flutter

It is necessary to pass the `localization` to the `bloc`, but the problem is that it is initialized to a lower level, is it possible to somehow swap them? If I could initialize the localization `S.delegate` first, then it is possible to pass it to the bloc constructor. Is there a solution for this?

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
            value: ConfigProvider(),
          ),
          ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
            value: ChannelProvider(),
          ),
          BlocProvider<InternetBloc>(
            create: (context) => InternetBloc(ticker: Ticker()),
          ),
          BlocProvider<MultiBloc>(
            create: (context) => MultiBloc(ticker: Ticker()),
          ),
          BlocProvider<DbBloc>(
            create: (context) => DbBloc(),
          ),
          BlocProvider<FileBloc>(
            create: (context) => FileBloc(),
          ),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp( 
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          localizationsDelegates: [
            S.delegate,
            GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
          ],
          supportedLocales: S.delegate.supportedLocales,
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
          ),
          home: StartPage(),
        ));
  }
}
```

`S.delegate` taken from the flutter documentation `Internationalizing Flutter apps` [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization) but in earlier versions of the documentation for some reason `AppLocalizations.delegate` was named `S.delegate` it is possible to write less with frequent use for example `Text(S.of(context).title)`  Why do I need internalization inside the bloc because it breaks the architecture? I need some exceptions that occur inside the bloc to be translated into several languages and become understandable to the users.

Comment: Please specify what is S, where and how do you initialize it, and where do you need to use it

Comment: @Pavel S its `AppLocalizations.delegate`. I have updated the question